# Using a Pyramid view for an AngularJS dialog template

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, pyramid, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have written a web application using [Pyramid](http://www.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/about), a Python web framework.

In one page of my web application, I'd like to implement dialogs. I'm trying to learn AngularJS with [AngularUI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/) to achieve this ([here an example of dialogs with AngularUI](http://plnkr.co/edit/IAEKqT?p=preview)).

My page will show a total of 7 dialogs. These dialogs will display text and images, and receive and validate input. Dialog flow is not linear; there are conditional dialogs and multiple branches of execution.

Please look at [this example of displaying an AngularUI Bootstrap dialog](http://plnkr.co/edit/IAEKqT?p=preview). `example.js:5-21` configures dialog display options. The parameter `template` contains the HTML to be displayed:

```
template:  t, // OR: templateUrl: 'path/to/view.html',
```

where, in the example, `var t` contains some static example markup:

```
var t = '<div class="modal-header">'+
        '<h3>This is the title</h3>'+
        ...
```

---

Now, In Pyramid, URLs are not mapped directly to files or folders; instead, URLs are [compared with registered routes](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/narr/firstapp.html#adding-configuration). So, for example, it does not make sense to request `http://site.com/path/to/view.html`. Instead, you would code:

`config.add_route('my_route', '/my_feature')`

`@view_config(route_name='my_route', renderer='/path/to/view.html')`

Which would render `view.html` if you call `http://site.com/my_feature`.

**How can I use a Pyramid view as a `templateUrl`?**

Because Pyramid abstracts URLs into views, I can't provide a `templateUrl` to a static HTML file (e.g. `abc.html`). Any URL I provide goes through Pyramid's routing system.

I've tried giving `templateUrl` to static HTML files with success. But any Pyramid-routed URL fails and the dialog doesn't show up.

What's the solution?

---

## Solution

I had accidentally used `template` instead of `templateUrl`.

Make sure it says `templateUrl: '/your-pyramid-view'` instead of `template: '/your-pyramid-view'`.

Comment: I've checked AngularUI code and all it does is perform a `GET` in order to load the template file. It doesn't do any validation whatsoever (the template could be any type of file). I assembled a small Sinatra app to test it, and everything worked fine. Are you sure your Pyramid-routed URL is working and returning any data?

Comment: Thanks Michael, your validation made me check over stupid careless errors.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to serve static html files with a static view:

```
config.add_static_view(name='partials', path='yourpythonpackage:partials')
```

If abc.html is in yourpythonpackage/partials then your `templateUrl` can be set to /partials/abc.html.

Comment: I didn't end up trying this because it worked after fixing a careless error, but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

And, don't forget the

`config.add_renderer('.html', 'pyramid.chameleon_zpt.renderer_factory')`

to render your front-end inedx.html directly, instead of a pyramid index template.